# AES Encryption / decryption for hindi character

Tags: objective-c

I m trying to decrypt the hindi character's using  Rijndael cipher algo(aes 128 encryption) but it is not working although code is able to encrypt hindi characters successfully and also it is working fine(both encryption/decryption) with english character.

im using the following classes for encryption/decryption https://github.com/DavidVeksler/CryptAByte

im using the following scenario 
plain text-->stringByEncodingHTMLEntities -->added padding to the key to make it multiple of 4--->base64EncodingWithLineLength.

what i think problem is that i m using 
static char encodingTable[64] = {
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'}
which for encoding which doesn't contains the hindi character set and

can any body help im realy not getting it. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: AES doesn't need to do anything special for Hindi, like everything else it works with, it's just binary data. A very significant rule when asking a programming question: first eliminate _all_ variables that are not necessary to understand or answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about AES with hindi characters, AES only handles bytes, does not care what the bytes might represent.

AES encrypt and decrypts bytes, that is all. You need to get your hindi character into a data stream, probably with the `NSString` method:

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

with encoding `NSUTF8StringEncoding'.

Then encrypt the data

Do something with the data, possibly being Base64 encoding and html entity encoding.
Reverse any of the above.

Then decrypt using the `NSString` method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

again with encoding `NSUTF8StringEncoding'.